# Uncaught Reference Error: Jquery is not defined

Tags: jquery, twitter

This is my first post, I'm not a programmer, just someone that cobbles together code from all over the web every once in a while for projects I'm working on.

I'm trying to implement a scrolling Twitter marquee on a website I'm working on, but am running into a "Uncaught Reference Error: Jquery not defined" error.

I assumed this was because Jquery was not being included correctly or the include was failing. I've tried the following:

1. Including the Jquery from different URLs, as well as hosting it locally
2. Changing the sequence of include statements in my  so that Jquery comes first

I found some similar threads on SO, but none of them help solve this.

Here's my code:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>UnBox 2013 : Venues</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/Volumes/Boot/Users/siddharthnair/Dropbox/UnBox 2013 Build/resonate/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton:400,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'/> 
<script src='/Volumes/Boot/Users/siddharthnair/Dropbox/UnBox 2013 Build/resonate/jquery.marquee.js'/> 


<script type='text/javascript'>

var Tweetstream = {
init: function () {
this.insertLatestTweets('unboxfestival');
}, 
insertLatestTweets: function (username) {
 var limit = 5; // How many feeds do you want?
 var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + username + '&count=' + limit + '&callback=?'; 

 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  var html = '<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left">';

  for (var i in data) {
   html += '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '#status_' + data[i].id_str + '">' + data[i].text + ' <i>' + Twitter.daysAgo(data[i].created_at) + '</i></a>';
  }

  html += '</marquee>';

  $('.tweetstream p').replaceWith(html);

  Twitter.fancyMarquee();
 });
}, 

fancyMarquee: function () {
 $('.tweetstream marquee').marquee('pointer')
  .mouseover(function () {
   $(this).trigger('stop');
  })
  .mouseout(function () {
   $(this).trigger('start');
  })
  .mousemove(function (event) {
   if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
    this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
   }
  })
  .mousedown(function (event) {
   $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
  })
  .mouseup(function () {
   $(this).data('drag', false);
  });
}, 

daysAgo: function (date) {
 // TODO: Fix date for IE...
 if ($.browser.msie) {
  return '1 day ago';
 }

 var d = new Date(date).getTime();
 var n = new Date().getTime();

 var numDays = Math.round(Math.abs(n - d) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 var daysAgo = numDays + ' days ago';

 if (numDays == 0) {
  daysAgo = 'today';
 }
 else if (numDays == 1) {
  daysAgo = numDays + ' day ago';
 }

 return daysAgo;
}
};

Tweetstream.init();
</script>
</head>
```

I hope this isn't spam, if there's a thread on here that you think answers the question, please feel free to just point me in the right direction.

Most of the code comes from here: http://andreaslagerkvist.com/archives/2011/06/24/how-to-create-a-scrolling-twitter-feed-using-jquery/

Comment: btw it is **jQuery**, not Jquery

Comment: Yes of course, you're right. I apologise, I think my noob is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add jquery script tag first and jquery code should be document.ready

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>UnBox 2013 : Venues</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="/Volumes/Boot/Users/siddharthnair/Dropbox/UnBox 2013 Build/resonate/style.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lekton:400,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js'/> 
<script src='/Volumes/Boot/Users/siddharthnair/Dropbox/UnBox 2013 Build/resonate/jquery.marquee.js'/> 


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
var Tweetstream = {
init: function () {
this.insertLatestTweets('unboxfestival');
}, 
insertLatestTweets: function (username) {
 var limit = 5; // How many feeds do you want?
 var url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + username + '&count=' + limit + '&callback=?'; 

 $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  var html = '<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="1" direction="left">';

  for (var i in data) {
   html += '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + username + '#status_' + data[i].id_str + '">' + data[i].text + ' <i>' + Twitter.daysAgo(data[i].created_at) + '</i></a>';
  }

  html += '</marquee>';

  $('.tweetstream p').replaceWith(html);

  Twitter.fancyMarquee();
 });
}, 

fancyMarquee: function () {
 $('.tweetstream marquee').marquee('pointer')
  .mouseover(function () {
   $(this).trigger('stop');
  })
  .mouseout(function () {
   $(this).trigger('start');
  })
  .mousemove(function (event) {
   if ($(this).data('drag') == true) {
    this.scrollLeft = $(this).data('scrollX') + ($(this).data('x') - event.clientX);
   }
  })
  .mousedown(function (event) {
   $(this).data('drag', true).data('x', event.clientX).data('scrollX', this.scrollLeft);
  })
  .mouseup(function () {
   $(this).data('drag', false);
  });
}, 

daysAgo: function (date) {
 // TODO: Fix date for IE...
 if ($.browser.msie) {
  return '1 day ago';
 }

 var d = new Date(date).getTime();
 var n = new Date().getTime();

 var numDays = Math.round(Math.abs(n - d) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 var daysAgo = numDays + ' days ago';

 if (numDays == 0) {
  daysAgo = 'today';
 }
 else if (numDays == 1) {
  daysAgo = numDays + ' day ago';
 }

 return daysAgo;
}
};
}
Tweetstream.init();
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's taken care of the error. However, the marquee itself doesn't seem to be working. Any chance you can help with that? I've checked: • Names and notation for the div that's being specified • Errors in the function name (If you look at the code I first pasted in here, there are two places where the function is being referred to as 'Twitter' whereas it should be 'Tweetstream'. This is an error I made when changing from the old version of the script that I'd copied.

Comment: hmm lil confusing to understand..just to make clear you use http://jsfiddle.net/ to create a test case of ur error and share the link..i can help then...

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the offer: http://jsfiddle.net/randomlysid/DGPAH/ Here you go, it's all the code I've got so far. I can't seem to get the tweetstream to display in the div under the header. I'm sure this is an elementary mistake I'm making, this is basically my way to teach myself html / css, so any help will do and your patience is appreciated!

Comment: lot of issues with this..to name few..`tweetstream.init` should be inside `document.ready` again...what do u want with this `$('.tweetstream marquee')`???

Answer (score 0):

Add type="text/javascript" to your jQuery reference tag -

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript">
```

In addition you will either want to move the single quote at the end of the URL or remove the slash.

Then enclose your code in a document ready wrapper -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```